# full width image can not be place in one fixed position with specified width and height

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I am making fading slideshow for front page. The images are full width. Here is my code;

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/slider/dental_clinick.jpg" alt="dental clinick" title="dental clinick" class="img"/>
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/slider/hospital_staff.jpg" alt="Hospital Staff Mohmand Hospital" title="Hospital Staff Mohmand Hospital" class="img"/>
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/slider/laboratory_test.jpg" alt="Laboratory Test Mohmand Hospital" title="Laboratory Test Mohmand Hospital" class="img"/>
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/slider/operation_theater.jpg" alt="Operation Theator Mohmand Hospital" title="Operation Theator Mohmand Hospital" class="img"/>
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/slider/operation_theator_staff.jpg" alt="Operation Theator Staff Mohmand Hospital" title="Operation Theator Staff Mohmand Hospital" class="img"/>
    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/display/photo/slider/xray.jpg" alt="X-Ray Mohmand Hospital" title="X-Ray Mohmand Hospital" class="img"/>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery;

```
$('.img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('.img:first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('.img').fadeIn(5000)
     .end().appendTo('#slider');}, 
  2000);
```

It seems that images are being place one under the other. When it turns to fadout for the next image to fadein, It shows moving down and next image comes out. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can we see the CSS? You may want to try absolute positioning for the images.

Comment: As a side note, you might try flexslider which is a very good slider plugin for jQuery which leverages CSS3 transitions if available among other niceities.  Like what happens when you get to the end of your slides?  Stylable navigation dots (or prev/next).  Being able to change between sliding and fading, easing, and being responsive. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#slider{position:relative;overflow:hidden}
#slider img{position:absolute;top:0;right:0}
```

Here is a jsfiddle for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/kingmotley/PWvaP/2/
Here is another jsfiddle using the img tag rather than the class, and only hiding img's within the slider: http://jsfiddle.net/kingmotley/PWvaP/3/

Comment: You may need to force your height/width on #slider as well, or put in a sample image that isn't hidden via display:none, but has the visibility:hidden style on it (or opacity:0) that isn't part of the slides to keep the right dimensions.

Comment: I have forced the #slider (height) but still it takes the maximum space for all the images. Suppose I have six images in slideshow. So, It takes all six images height (scroll is shown) but the other images are hidden. How to fix the other images issue, Otherwise the slideshow is working well.

Comment: If you see the scroll bar, then you didn't apply the CSS above correctly.  `overflow:hidden` should get rid of the scroll bars, while the `position:relative` and `position:absolute` stuff renders all the images on top of each other.

Comment: It is working. But it is not working with me. Can you add me on skype so that I show you the problem. My Skype is arif_shariati

Comment: I can't skype currently, sorry.

Comment: Sorry @Robert McKee. Your solution was actually working on my live serve but not in my localhost. May be it was due to some bugs. Thanks dear once again

Comment: Are you wrapping your javascript code in a document ready function?  Perhaps either some assets or script load timings are different.

Comment: Yes. I do follow the basic concept in JQuery